# Find Element in PHP Array (if exists)

Tags: php

I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this:

```
$foo = (isset($bar) and array_key_exists('meh', $bar)) ? $bar['meh'] : '';
```

If I remove the `isset` part, PHP issues a warning if `$bar` isn't an array, if I remove the `array_key_exists` part, PHP issues a warning if the `meh` key isn't in the array.  Is there a more graceful, warning free, way of achieving the same end?

Comment: I do the same... but have it as a function... oh and a default value (might not always want empty string... might want 0, or null, or empty object etc etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You take exactly the steps required to "secure" code against the warnings you mention.

However, the warnings are there for a reason. Typically it makes more sense to check, if you can prevent situations where the variables you are trying to access are not initialized.

Comment: +1 for suggesting you know your data. This does not really answer the question but the suggestion itself is very valuable. The PHP community often embraces defensive programming (where you try to handle or hide all errors), but it is often much easier to debug *offensive* programs which fails on invalid inputs.

Comment: Point taken. Initialize the variable as opposed to suppressing the error.

Answer (score 2):

You can reference the key directly. Inside `isset` it won't even throw an exception if $bar is undefined.

```
$foo = isset($bar['meh']) ? $bar['meh'] : '';
```

The difference between [array_key_exists](http://php.net/array_key_exists) and [isset](http://php.net/isset) is that `isset` will return `FALSE` if the key corresponds to a `NULL` value. In my code above, a `NULL` value will therefore result in `$foo` begin the empty string, not `NULL`. If that is a problem your current approach will be the best.